# How to get Display Name from Manager(Person field) userprofile - SharePoint 2010

Tags: user-profile-service

I'm using powershell to get some data from userprofile but I cant get to display the Managers field name as its a person field.
What I currently get it domain\username .
How can I get a display name .

```
   $Manager = $profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::Manager].Value
```

Above is how Im currently getting the Managers field.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code, use the domain\username of the Manager and get the userprofile object of the Manager. From that you will be able to get all the details you require

```
$site=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("https://c05470sp10:7443");            
$serviceContext = Get-SPServiceContext $site;            
$site.Dispose();            
$upm = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($serviceContext);            
$userProfile = $upm.GetUserProfile("company\accountid");
$userProfileManager = $upm.GetUserProfile($userProfile["Manager"].Value);
$userProfileManager["Name"].Value
```

Reference: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20692.sharepoint-2013-get-set-and-copy-user-profile-properties-using-powershell.aspx

Comment: Thanks Nagarajan but its not working.I'm getting value cannot be null despite hard coding "company\accountid"

Comment: Tried email address as suggested in the reference but getting error - something wrong with retrieving the user profile