# Powershell - How to get Manager's name from UPS

Tags: powershell, user-profile-property

How do I get manager's name instead of sAMAccount? I was following the powershell link (see below) to populate a list.

I tried this `$user.Item("Manager").Value;` or `$user.Item("Manager").Name;` but no success

https://www.sharepointusecases.com/2012/11/use-case-export-user-profiles-to-a-sharepoint-list-phonebook-style/

Answer (score 0):

**I know this is too late to answer but for future reference, I will and my answer below.**

```
add-pssnapin microsoft.SharePoint.powershell

$site=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("SITECOLLECTIONURL");            
$serviceContext = Get-SPServiceContext $site;  
$web=Get-spweb -identity "SPWEBURL"          
$site.Dispose();            
$upm = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($serviceContext);            
$userProfile = $upm.GetUserProfile("m.prabhashwara@qapco.com.qa");


#Name
    write-host $userProfile.GetManager().DisplayName

#Email
$userProfile.GetManager().AccountName
$spManager = $web.EnsureUser($userProfile.GetManager().AccountName)
 write-host $spManager.Email
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a post on this site [How to get Display Name from Manager(Person field) userprofile - SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159871/how-to-get-display-name-from-managerperson-field-userprofile-sharepoint-2010) and it helped. Here is the full code that works for my need.

```
# https://www.sharepointusecases.com/2012/11/use-case-export-user-profiles-to-a-sharepoint-list-phonebook-style
if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
}
function Enumerate-SPUserProfiles($webUrl, $listName)
{
    $x= [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
    $x= [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("microsoft.sharepoint.portal")
    $x= [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server")
    $x= [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web")
    $sites = Get-SPSite
    $context = [Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext]::GetContext($sites[0])
    $profileManager = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
    $web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
    $list = $web.Lists[$listName]
    $profileManager.GetEnumerator() | ?{$_.DisplayName -notlike '*\*' -and $_.ProfileType -eq "User" } | foreach-object { Update-PhoneBook $_ $web $list $webUrl }
}

function Update-PhoneBook($user, $web, $list, $webUrl)
{
    if($user.Item("FirstName") -ne "" -and $user.Item("FirstName") -ne $null -and $user.Item("EmployeeID") -ne $null)
    {
        $spQuery = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
        $userName = $user.Item("UserName")
        $camlQuery = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UserName' /><Value Type='Text'>$userName</Value></Eq></Where>";
        $spQuery.Query = $camlQuery
        $spQuery.RowLimit = 1
        $spListItemCollection = $list.GetItems($spQuery)
        $domain = (gwmi WIN32_ComputerSystem).Domain

        if($spListItemCollection.Count -ge 1)
        {
            Write-Host "Updating $username..."
            Update-Contact $spListItemCollection[0] $user $domain $webUrl 
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "Adding $username..."
            $contact = $list.items.add();
            Update-Contact $contact $user $domain $webUrl 
        }
    }
}

function Update-Contact($contact, $user, $domain, $webUrl)
{
    $contact["Title"] = $user.Item("title");
    $contact["EmployeeName"] = $user.Item("PreferredName");
    $contact["Employee ID"] = $user.Item("EmployeeID");
    $contact["EmployeeLocation"] = $user.Item("Office");

    $sites2 = Get-SPSite $webUrl
    $context2 = [Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext]::GetContext($sites2[0])
    $profileManager2 = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context2)
    $manager = $user.Item("Manager")
    $upSupervisor = $profileManager2.GetUserProfile($manager.Split('\')[1]);
    $contact["ManagersName"] =  $upSupervisor["PreferredName"];

    $contact["Department"] = $user.Item("Department");
    $contact["UserName"] = $user.Item("AccountName");

    $contact.update()
}

#You can run it by typing:
Enumerate-SPUserProfiles "https://train.thoshiba.br.pt" "Employees List TEST"
```

Comment: he already mentioned the same script / link in his question/